# JVM: How much RAM must be provided for best performance - to not to use pagefile

Tags: operating-system, jvm

I wonder how much memory must be proivided for better JVM performance.
It obvious that much is better, but I'm afraid of this kind of situtation:

For example:
I have total 8Gb of RAM.
5 GB already consumed by OS. 
I give my JVM -Xmx6000m.

So my question is - When JVM will consume 3Gb of it's 6Gb will it start accessing to pagefile and will slow down ? (pagefile is on HDD and every read is much slower that RAM access)

Or is it best decision to provide only 3Gb ?

Answer (score 0):

Run JConsole or VisualVM to monitor the actual memory usage of your JVM and start tuning from there.

And yes I would prefer to run everything in physical RAM too, but that is more a matter of gut feeling than actual knowledge ;-).

Comment: But this will show me only internal JVM memory usage. There is no information about OS commits/hardfaults.

Comment: That is true. But is will help you dimension your JVM memory settings. You might not even need 3GB.